# Show that a and b are equidistant from the arithmetic mean of a and b

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a < b$ and $$a < \frac{a+b}{2} <b$$
Show that the arithmetic mean of a and b is equidistant from a and b.

My attempt:
Suppose a and b are equidistant from $\frac{a+b}{2}$
then $$\frac{a+b}{2} - \frac a 2 = \frac{a+b}{2} - \frac b 2$$
$$a + b - a = a + b -b$$
$$b = a$$
Since $a=b$ the arithmetic mean of a and b is equidistant from a and b.

Comment: If you want to "Show X" why do you start your proof from "Suppose X" ?

Comment: "Since $a=b$" (at the end) is not compatible with $a<b$ (at the beginning) !

Comment: Yikes, @N.F.Taussig I blindly copy-pasted the OP’s mathjax and committed a blunder lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You have to show that

$$\frac{a+b}{2} -a=b-\frac{a+b}{2} .$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose it isn't.  Then we want to show that $$\frac{a+b}2-a\neq b-\frac{a+b}2.$$ But on the left, we have $$\frac{a+b}2-a=\frac{a+b-2a}2=\frac{b-a}2,$$ and on the right, we have $$b-\frac{a+b}2=\frac{2b-a-b}2=\frac{b-a}2$$ as well.

Comment: I think it should be $\frac{a+b-2a}2$ rather than $\frac{2+b-2a}2$

Comment: @Rolomoto yeah I wonder what happened Oops